# Как останавливать функцию на js?

Tags: javascript

Создал простой Таймер

```
  function timer() {
  setInterval(function timer() {
    var label = document.getElementById('label');
    label.innerHTML = parseInt(label.innerHTML) + 1;
}, 1000);
  }
```

Так вот как можно останавливать его внутри другой функции? Без использования Jquery!

Comment: в текущем виде - никак. _setInterval_ - возвращает id таймера к которому можно применить clearInterval, но так как сейчас все это остается внутри функции timer - применять clearInterval не к чему

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
var i = 0;
var timerId = 0;

function timer() {
timerId = setInterval(function () {  
     //Здесь код в цикле 
     console.log(i++);
}, 1000);   
}

function stopTimer(){
clearInterval(timerId);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="StartTimer" onclick="timer()" /> <br>
<input type="button" value="StopTimer" onclick="stopTimer()" />
```

setInterval возвращает id, который нужно передать clearInterval(id), для того чтоб остановилось, см. пример

Comment: Ну я хочу останавливать функцию кликом, но не через определенное количество времени

Comment: обновил пример, вызови stopTimer, так?

Comment: А можно пример именно конкретно с моим кодом?

Answer (score 3):

Функции `setTimeout` и `setInterval` возвращают идентификатор, который можно передать в функции остановки таймеров `clearTimeout` и `clearInterval` соответственно.
Нужно просто сохранить возвращённый `id` и, при надобности, передать его в очищающую функцию.
Например так:

```js
function timer() {
  // Сохраняем в свойстве объекта функции, индивидуально и внешние переменные не нужны
  timer.id = setInterval(() => {
    let label = document.querySelector('#label');
    label.innerHTML = (parseInt(label.innerHTML) || 0) + 1;
  }, 1000);
}

// По клику запускаем таймер
document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', e => timer());

// По клику запускаем функцию очистки, т. к. timer.id - не приватное свойство
// P. S. Кнопкой старта можно продолжить счёт
document.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', e => clearInterval(timer.id));
```

```html
<div id='label'>0</div><br />
<input type='button' id='start' value='Start!' /><br />
<input type='button' id='stop' value='Stop!' />
```

Comment: А можно что бы он сам по себе не запускался ?

Comment: @arthru, конечно - просто не запускать функцию `timer();` (8-ая строчка `JS`). Тогда нужно вызвать её там, где нужно - обработчик клика, пятое марта на часах или 4:30 на календаре.

Comment: А как можно по нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: @arthru, обновил ответ.